# How to query a JIRA ISSUE from CTO Domain

Tags: jira, jql

We are currently hosted in CEDT domain of JIRA and i have created a simple filter to view issues assigned to particular resources. However while in CEDT domain, i need to also view issues assigned to a resource for another project which is hosted in CTO domain of JIRA. Is there a way to do the same?
Summary - While in CEDT domain of JIRA, i need to view issues which are in CTO domain. Appreciate all your help on this

I tried to search on the basis of column "domain" etc but couldn't find any such column to filter on.

Comment: CEDT domain - is this your atlassian cloud instance url what mean by that?

Comment: yes @MarkoSlijepčević - CEDT is our atlassian cloud instance url. CTO is another atlassian instance. I want to pull JIRA from CTO instance in CEDT instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is currently not available in Atlassian products. Maybe, a third-party plugin could help? I once came across the WatchTower plugin for some multi-instance Kanban boards for Jira, maybe this can help you in some way.